# How to tar all files in current directory using tar but without inputing names of tar file and all files?

Tags: unix, command-line, tar

## ENV:

- macOS Sierra 10.12.6

## Raw input(example):

```
.
├── f1.md
├── f2.md
├── f3.md
├── f4.txt
├── f5.csv
└── f6.doc

0 directories, 6 files
```

In a test folder, there are 6 files.

## Expected output:

```
.
├── all.tar
├── f1.md
├── f2.md
├── f3.md
├── f4.txt
├── f5.csv
└── f6.doc

0 directories, 7 files
```

## Trying and Problem

```
tar -cvf all.tar f1.md f2.md f3.md f4.txt f5.csv f6.doc
```

Though I get the result from the above method but I have to inputing all file names and the compressed file name, which is inconvenient. For example , I can select all files and right click, then choose compressed option without inputing `all.tar` (I don't mind the .tar filenames.)

## Hope

command-line method without inputing specific file names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you want all files, including those in the subdirectories (or if you have no subdirectories), you would run:

```
tar -cvf all.tar *
```

Then, `bash` would expand `*` into the list of all files in the current directory, including subdirectories.

In case you want only those files in the current directory, but NOT in the subdirectories, then you would have to use `find`, in a more complicated command.  Let me know if this is the case for you, and I can take the time to find that combination of commands for you.

Comment: `*` would miss hidden files, unfortunately, and requires a shell for expansion.